# numpy array having issues with initialization

Tags: python, numpy

Am on Python 3.4, Winpython 64bits.

This code is fine:

```
np.empty((6,2), dtype=object)
```

With this code, the ipython is blocked... and need to relaunch Spyder:

```
tablr1= np.empty((6,2), dtype=object)
```

It sounds a bit quite strange (I have never seen this...and still wondering on this can happen...)

EDITED:

It seems related to the assignment of variable by an empty array....

Comment: Both your snippets run fine by. Perhaps try to reboot your computer and start afresh.

Comment: Yes, I just did.... I try on Python 2.7 and it run fine.... but still have the issues in 3.4  (am very suprised).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it was a Spyder bug (on the display of variable side). no more visible in latest WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2b3.exe.

upgrading to spyder 3.0.0b3 is not recommanded on previous WinPython release, because the Spyder icon won't work (a breaking change occured).

Comment: It is probably this reason since on Python 3.4, it works... Very strange one